# For $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}, \exists K>0$ such that $|f(x)|+|f'(x)| \leq \frac{K}{1+x^2} \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given $a>0$, for $f(x) = \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}, \exists K>0$ such that $|f(x)|+|f'(x)| \leq \frac{K}{1+x^2} \; \forall x \in  \mathbb{R}$

This is a property that my pde book used without proving. It is supposed to be true, but I´m failing to verify.

I got:

$f’(x) = \displaystyle \frac{-2x}{(a^2+x^2)^2}$, then $|f(x)|+|f'(x)| = \frac{1}{a^2+x^2} + \frac{2|x|}{(a^2+x^2)^2} = \frac{a^2+2|x|+x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^2} $. What can be this constant $K$?

Exercise photo from the book:[image]

It says: Apply the above formula (i) to the function $f(x) = (a^2+x^2)^{-1}$ to obtain the series below. It works when I apply the function, but why does this  hypothesis of (i) holds for this $f$?

Comment: If $a=0$, LHS of the inequality grows without bounds as $x\to 0$ while RHS is bounded by $K$. Have you got the expressions correctly?

Comment: @Macavity I think we should assume $a \neq 0$

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides Even if one assumes that, you’ll always have a nbd of $0$ where the inequality fails. Take any $a\in (0, 1/\sqrt K)$ for a counter example.

Comment: oh, sorry! yes, $a>0$

Comment: @Macavity, so the inequality isn´t valid for this function? That´s weird, it´s also in  an exercise of my pde book...

Comment: Perhaps you can provide which book and page #. If $a\neq0$ and $K$ is allowed to depend on $a$, it could work. Or maybe the RHS denominator should have $a^2+x^2$ in it. The text may clarify.

Comment: Sadly it is in portuguese and there´s no english translation, I think. EDP Um Curso de Graduação, by Valéria Iório, page 200. I´ll try to take a picture of the exercise.

Comment: I added a photo of the exercise from the book. Sorry for my terrible camera :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x):=(1+x^2)(|f(x)|+|f'(x)|)$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} g(x)$ are finite and $g$ doesn't have any vertical asymptote we conclude that there exists $K=K(a) > 0$ such that 
$$g(x) \leq  K \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R,$$ or equivalently 
$$ |f(x)|+|f'(x)| \leq \frac{K}{1+x^2} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R. $$

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks a lot!